# Find solutions to equation (ring/field theory, residue class)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, field-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> A **residue class ring** mod $n$ is a field if **n is prime**. Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a residue ring, p prime. Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.
>
> What are all solutions $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ to the following equation?
>
> $$\widetilde{x^2} = \widetilde{a²}$$

Here's what I've tried so far (note: $a^{\#}$ is the inverse of a, n is identity element):

$\widetilde{x^2} = \widetilde{a²}$

$\iff \widetilde{x^2} \cdot (\widetilde{a^{\#}})^2 = \widetilde{a²} \cdot (\widetilde{a^{\#}})^2$

$\iff \widetilde{x^2} \cdot (\widetilde{a^{\#}})^2 = \widetilde{a} \cdot \widetilde{a} \cdot \widetilde{a^{\#}} \cdot \widetilde{a^{\#}}$

$\iff \widetilde{x} \cdot \widetilde{x} \cdot \widetilde{a^{\#}} \cdot \widetilde{a^{\#}} = \widetilde{a} \cdot n \cdot \widetilde{a^{\#}}$

$\iff \widetilde{(xxa^{\#}a^{\#})} = \widetilde{a \cdot a^{\#}}$

$\iff \widetilde{(xxa^{\#}a^{\#})} = \widetilde{1}$

$\iff \widetilde{x \cdot a^{\#}} \widetilde{x\cdot a^{\#}} = \widetilde{1}$

$\iff (\widetilde{x \cdot a^{\#}   })^{2} = \widetilde{1}$

This is where I'm stuck. Can anyone help me solve this?

Edit: For all of those unfamiliar with the tilde notation: It indicates the residue class of whatever is below. Another way of stating the problem would (I think) be: Solve for x in the following equation:

$$x^2 mod \space n = a^2 mod \space n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $a \in K$.
Consider the equation $x^2 = a^2$.
Since $x^2 - a^2 = (x - a)(x + a) = 0, x = \pm a$.

Comment: So simple! Thank you! :)